# How to fix Gnome Clock on Bar (date command seems to not use correct timezone)

Tags: date, timezone, clock

Fedora 37 with Gnome Shell 43. On Status Bar on the top I see wrong time. But When I opening Gnome Clock app (this one https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Clocks) then I see correct time

[image: Screenshot]

Also when I typing `date` in termina I see correct `UTC` time but wrong local

[image]

But my timezone seems to be correct

[image]

Context:

- In Poland there is UTC+1
- In Bangkok (my current location) there is UTC+7

I do not have file `/etc/timezone`

Command `timedatectl status` shows correct informations:

```
timedatectl status
               Local time: nie 2023-02-19 10:07:48 +07
           Universal time: nie 2023-02-19 03:07:48 UTC
                 RTC time: nie 2023-02-19 03:07:48
                Time zone: Asia/Bangkok (+07, +0700)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

So question is:

- why `date` command uses my old timezone (I had UTC+4 in Dubai 2 weeks ago, but it should be updated now)
- how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by checking

```
man date
```

and seeing `TZ` variable. I had `TZ=Asia/Dubai` globally.

So to fix I had to:

- remove this variable
- set to `Asia/Bangkok`